# Python list append to list "AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'append'"

Tags: python, list, split, append, tuples

Alright so I know you cannot append a tuple to a list. However I am still receiving this error despite my best efforts. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong or what is going on?

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:/Users/.py", line 31, in 
>       listRow.append(convertedList)
>   AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'append'

followedBy is a string that comes from a cursor and is split into a list form. Below is some sample data that the cursor would contain.

followedBy = "0| 1| 2| 40"

```
table = [] #contains all rows (table)
row = [] #contains row
listFollowedBy = [] #contains ids 

for (var1, var2, var3, followedBy) in cursor:
   row = var1, var2, var3
   listFollowedBy = followedBy.split("| ") #Thought split always split the data into lists
   convertedList = list(listFollowedBy) #Threw this in there just to insure it was converted to a list
   row.append(convertedList)

   table.append(row)
```

Comment: Split does split as a list, you just can't keep track of your variables because they all have similar names.

Comment: Make sure you fix followed by. It looks like it should be a string.

Comment: `row` is a tuple as defined at the moment (you bind it to a list and then you  rebind it to a tuple within your `for` suite).  Change to `row = [var1, var2, var3]`

Comment: That was a typo in the question.This reflects more code more closely.

Comment: Row is a tuple! You're appending a list to a tuple. No can do!

Comment: You have edited the question now  but still  `row = var1, var2, var3` binds row to a tuple. You need to put the three variables within [ ] as per my earlier comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tuples are immutable meaning they can't be changed unless reassigned. You can however add tuples to a list because lists are mutable, meaning they can be changed. You need to edit the order of your append.

```
listFollowedBy.append(row)
```

As of now, your row is a tuple. Tuples don't have an append method, lists do. Why are you appending a list to a tuple instead of a tuple to a list? You've got the method call backwards.

Comment: Its not a tuple its a list. Split should split it to a list. I also even converted it to a list just to double check

Comment: @user3586062 You don't understand. The append method is called on the list not the tuple.